# Can I delete a DB from azure while is being restored from a BACPAC file?

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, database-restore, bacpac

I have a BACPAC file that is being restored into a new database. Later, I realized that I don't need the DB anymore. The problem is that it has not finished to restored yet.

The question is that I can delete the DB while is restoring and be sure that nothing is going to happend to the BACPAC file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bacpac is just the (read-only) source of the restore and nothing can affect its structure.

In the other hand, you cannot delete a database that does not exist yet. Once the restore has finished you will be able to delete it.

Run the following query to monitor the progress of the restore operation:

> SELECT * FROM sys.dm_operation_status ORDER BY start_time DESC;

To know the progress of a RESTORE operation on SQL Server On-premises I used below query:

```
SELECT session_id as SPID, command, a.text AS Query, start_time,
 percent_complete, dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as 
 estimated_completion_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a  
WHERE r.command in ('RESTORE DATABASE')
```

Remove the WHERE clause from the query when restoring from a bacpac so you can identify which statement is doing the restore.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for SQL Server? I can only find documentation for Azure SQL.

Comment: You mean an equivalent of sys.dm_operation_status for SQL Server On-premises? Are you looking for a way to measure the progress of restoring a bacpac on SQL Server On-premises?

Comment: Yes. I was not aware of dm_operation_status for Azure SQL so I was wondering if there is a similar command for SQL Server.

Comment: I will update my answer with the answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you. I knew about this command. Your solution for Azure SQL was so clean and simple that I thought I missed something for SQL Server. Microsoft should back port some of the new Azure SQL features.

Comment: You can create a Connect item suggesting sys.dm_operation_status to be supported on SQL Server on-premises. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback